# Javascript not getting text file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to recreate the typing effect in Hackertyper.com - so I am scraping some of the code and trying to work with it.

It seems that it's not getting the txt file (helloworld.txt) . The addText function is loading, however it stops loading after "if(Typer.txt)". So I am thinking it might be an error in this specific part:

Question:  Why is the file not being loaded and the callback not called? (in case it wasn't clear)

```
init: function(){// inizialize Hacker Typer
$.get(Typer.file,function(data){// get the text file
    Typer.text=data;// save the textfile in Typer.text
});
},
```

All of the javascript code:

```
$(
function(){
    $("#message").keydown(
        function ( event ) { 
            Typer.addText( event ); //Capture the keydown event and call the addText, this is executed on page load
        }
    );
}
);


var Typer={
text: null,
index:0, // current cursor position
speed:2, // speed of the Typer
file:"helloworld.txt", //file, must be set

init: function(){// inizialize Hacker Typer
    $.get(Typer.file,function(data){// get the text file
        Typer.text=data;// save the textfile in Typer.text
    });
},

content:function(){
    return $("#message").html();// get console content
},

write:function(str){// append to console content
    $("#message").append(str);
    return false;
},


addText:function(key){//Main function to add the code
    if(Typer.text){ // otherway if text is loaded
        var cont=Typer.content(); // get the console content
        if(cont.substring(cont.length-1,cont.length)=="|") // if the last char is the blinking cursor
            $("#message").html($("#message").html().substring(0,cont.length-1)); // remove it before adding the text
        if(key.keyCode!=8){ // if key is not backspace
            Typer.index+=Typer.speed;   // add to the index the speed
        }else{
            if(Typer.index>0) // else if index is not less than 0 
                Typer.index-=Typer.speed;// remove speed for deleting text
        }
        var text=$("<div/>").text(Typer.text.substring(0,Typer.index)).html();// parse the text for stripping html enities
    }
},

}
```

The HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="input-title">
    Post an update:
  </div>

  <div id="message" contenteditable="true" class="text"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The question is, why the file is not loaded and callback not called.

Comment: Guys, could anyone explain me what the `$( ... )` wrapper is supposed to do? It's weird.

Comment: It binds the function to jQuery's ready event. Read the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). `$` is just a shortcut for `jQuery`

Comment: In order to answer the question we'll need you to provide more information then that. When running on google Chrome, you can use developer tools to debug. When on Firefox, you can use Firebug to debug. Using one of the two, can you tell us what's inside Typer.Text when your addText function is called? Also, where is the helloworld.txt located in your project files? Which page is the javascript on and where is it located in your files?

Comment: I am not sure what's your first question - Nothing appears inside my "message" div, except for what I type. Helloworld.txt is in my root folder, and my JS files are in root/JS/application.js .

Comment: When on chrome or firefox, use CTRL + SHIFT + I or press F12 in order to open developer tools or firebug. When one or the other is opened, you can go in "source" for chrome or "Debug" for firefox. Select your javascript file and place a "breakpoint" on the line where the if(Typer.Text) is situated. When running the page, the browser should stop at the breakpoint. You can then mouse over Typer to see what information is stored in your Typer variable. My question is, what's in Typer.Text when you reach the addText function?

Comment: @snaplemouton Oh ok, thanks for explaining. It appears to be 'null'. When I mouse over:  `addText: function (key){//Main function to add the code
content: function (){
file: "helloworld.txt"
index: 0
init: function (){// inizialize Hacker Typer
speed: 2
text: null
write: function (str){// append to console content
__proto__: Object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several errors there, have a look at them:

1. You've forgotten to call `Typer.init()`
2. You're sending `event` to the `.addText` method. It expects key code.
3. You're not cancelling keydown event (`event.preventDefault();`)

Let me see if I get it to work on jsFiddle.

Edit: I didn't, but it [works here.](http://u8.8u.cz/hackertype.php)

Comment: You should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), @blazemonger was kind enough to edit your answer... yet you rolled back the edit.

Comment: The first sentence is rude toward the OP.

Comment: You have a better formulation of the obvious fact on your mind?

Comment: Courtesy isn't about being truthful, it's about respect for others. We were all new to this at one time. I've gotten help from people who were understanding and polite despite answering the same type of question for the hundredth time, and I've been told "RTFM" and had my question deleted, and I've preferred the understanding and polite approach every single time.

Comment: I respect lack of knowledge, but not lack, of rather absence of effort. And the fact that questions like this one are usually left open because OP finds the error just few moments after posting their question (because it was **that** easy).

Comment: If you read the comments on her first post you can see she doesn't know how to debug. If you look at her profile it state clearly she is a designer more then a developer and she specify she is a beginner. Like Blazemonger said, we were all new at this once and there is no better way to learn then being told politely what we can do to improve ourself.

Comment: So my  last comment was deleted. I now see the dark side of SO community. If you have enough reputation you're always right.